# String decryption for webservice

Tags: java, web-services, security, encryption, md5

I have a web service (Java) which requires a password for all cases. But the password must be come to me securely. Is there a standard way for all platforms -> java encryption/decryption. How can I decrypt a string which could come a random platform(php,.net,iPhone).

Comment: The standard is called SSL/TLS. Don't try any cute hashing techniques, you'll get them wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually passwords are encrypted using some algorithm say (MD5) and exchange with services... You don't have to decrypt password... it's like you create a MD5 hash string of password and the key is the actual password it self.

So on server, you would store MD5 hash of actual password and each client will create MD5 hash string of given password and finally you would validate both hash strings for password verification...

You would easily find java code online to create MD5 hash... one example is

```
public static String convertStringToMD5Hash(String string) {
    byte[] hash;

    try {
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("MD5 not supported?", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("UTF-8 not supported?", e);
    }

    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);

    for (byte b : hash) {
        int i = (b & 0xFF);
        if (i < 0x10)
            hex.append('0');
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString(i));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}
```

> Disclaimer: Code works on my machine and may need
>   improvement/optimization for production use

Comment: Also check DigestUtils in apache commons codec (commons.apache.org)

Comment: in my database passwords are masking a simple algorithm and i cant switch them to md5. So if a php client sent me a encrypted string i must get the password from db and encrypt with same method then compare them. How can i sure if encryption produce the same string in java.

Comment: that is bad... which algorithm are you using to store passwords in database and can you recover actual password from them? its better to use standard algorithms on both side...

Comment: actually algorithm is very simple masking, and created by our old programmer. and yes i can recover actual password with db's value. As i said previously i can't change anything on db. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Well a hack would be to retrieve password and generate MD5 hash and then compare with the MD5 hash string generated from client

Comment: Thanks a lot. with your guidanceand codes above, i resolve the problem.

Comment: @AdilMughal So if the hash now becomes the password, how do you protect the hash while it is being transmitted? Quoting his question "the password must be come to me securely"...

Comment: @JoãoFernandes hash can only be recovered if u know the original password due to its one sided nature of encryption.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes We perhaps passed kind of similar way in 2-legged oAuth implementation.

Comment: @AdilMughal First, hashing and encrypting are two different things, therefore used for different purposes. Hashed data is "not" recoverable, ciphered data is. In an authentication system, you may save the hash of the client's password on the server instead of its actual password (and salted please...). This ensures that if someone stills your server database, they will "not" be able to know the clients' actual passwords. However, it's totally wrong to build an auth system on top of the idea that the client will send the hash of its pass to server in order to auth himself. That's plain wrong.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes Thanks for sharing your thoughts... I would study this further.

Answer (score 0):

Use WS-Security Username Token, which ensures it will address cross platform.

http://wso2.org/library/240 (Rampart)

or

use Apache WSS4J

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-Axis2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just like @CodesInChaos said in his comment, use SSL/TLS. If you really praise security don't consider any other option. If we want to be creative in this area, well, you assume the risks...

Comment: There is also a debate on compromising SSL certificate in mobile apps due to chances of reverse engineering on platform such as Android, Windows etc.

Comment: @AdilMughal The protocol is known as secure. If we start discussing about attacks that are based on changes to certificates, no secure system exists.